# how to create aliases for full git commands

Tags: git, gerrit, repo

I created a git alias as follows but when I run `git gbf4364` it throws an error, what am I missing?

```
git config --global alias.gbf4364 'git clone ssh://username@gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/projectname'
```

Comment: What is the value you want to provide for gbf4364? It should be git config --global alias.gbf4364 <value> you can still list all the global configurations 
git config --list

Comment: Can you share your error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git aliases are assumed to be git commands unless stated otherwise. Git simply replaces the new command with whatever you alias it for. However, maybe you want to run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with a `!` character<sup>[1](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)</sup>.

As `clone` is a git subcommand, use `git config --global alias.gbf4364 'clone ssh://username@gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/projectname'`, which will translate to `git clone [...]`

You shouldn't add  `git` in the alias.
Otherwise `git gbft4364` equals to `git git clone ssh://username@gerrit.sd.company.com:29418/projectname`, it will have two git.

When you want to delete the alias, use `git config --global --unset alias.gbft4364`